# WordPress doesn't show posts' details

Tags: wordpress-theming

Just deloyed a WordPress site on internet, using apache2.4+ PHP7+phpmyadmin+MySQL5+newestWordPress.The homepage can be visited as xxx.xx.xx.xx by explorer.
But there are 2 problems)
1.It doesn't show posts' details like imgs .
2.Only main page is available.Clicking a post title will cause (request is denied).

Problems show on visitors'end, things look going fine for WordPress admin.

Hope some friends here could help to diagnose...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a staging server, looks like that.